# Controlling a UserControl's Storyboard from the parent Window in WPF using only XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have created a very simple test app to try and solve this problem described to me by a co-worker.  He was able to trigger it in C#, but I believe he needed the solution to be more generic and wanted it to be done strictly in the XAML.  The problem was: How do you trigger the Storyboard inside of a UserControl to begin in response to an event on a control in the containing Window (the parent doesn't have to be a Window, it can be a Page or another UserControl...I use a Window for simplicity).  So, my best example is that you have a Window with a Button and an instance of your UserControl.  You want the Click event of the Button to trigger a Storyboard inside of the UserControl to begin.

Inside of the UserControl itself, the Storyboard is declared as a Resource with the key of MyStoryboard.  I created a Button with an EventTrigger to show that I could trigger the Storyboard by referencing it with a Binding expression.  Here is the complete XAML for my UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlStoryboard.UserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Height="300" Width="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MyStoryboard">
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).Color" From="CadetBlue" To="White" Duration="0:0:2" />
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Background="CadetBlue" x:Name="grid">
    <Button Content="Press Me" Height="50">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" Path="Resources[MyStoryboard]" />
                    </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>            
</Grid>
```

I was hoping that since I was able to tell a Storyboard to begin by referencing it with a Binding expression that I should be able to do the exact same thing from a Window that contains this UserControl as a child element.  But I can't seem to figure out how to get a reference to the Storyboard inside of the parent Window.  Is this impossible to accomplish in XAML only?

The parent window in my test project has nothing but a button and an instance of this UserControl.  If it's even possible, which element would let me add an EventTrigger where the source of the event is the Button and the trigger action tells the UserControl's Storyboard to begin?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a very similar situation, did you ever find a resolution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  This question was asked two years ago.  Since then I've done some really hacky things with template bindings to communicate back and forth between parent and child controls.  Having this experience behind me now, I'd actually favor the more straight-forward C# approach.  The more fancy tricks I see done with xaml, bindings, viewmodels, etc the more I cringe...can make a huge debugging nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea of responding to external events within UserControl is not a very safe one. Within UserControl, you'd want to react only to events that are born within the control.

Can you flip the situation around and do the following: ?

- Expose the UC property that needs to be animated as a dependency property (background in this case)
- Create both EventTrigger and Storyboard on the parent window

Comment: "I think the idea of responding to external events within UserControl is not a very safe one".  Why?  This concept goes way back to ActiveX controls or ActiveX documents responding to Ambient Properties in the host container.  Sure, now we are talking about WPF but the concept is the same I think

Answer (score 1):

You can access the storyboard by using the StaticResource. You need only assign the resource to the Storyboard on the BeginStroyboard.

```
<BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyStoryboard}">
</BeginStoryboard>
```

I changed the code to the following and when you press the button, it will start the storyboard for you. Hope this helps.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MyStoryboard">
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).Color" From="CadetBlue" To="White" Duration="0:0:2" />
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Background="CadetBlue" x:Name="grid">
    <Button Content="Press Me" Height="50">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyStoryboard}">
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't a good way to do it with pure Xaml.

You can:

- Make a dependency property on your UserControl that takes a Button, then you can bind to it.
- Make some kind of crazy converter that traverses your visual tree looking for something in particular.

Both require some C#, so I don't know if any of the above is what you are looking for.