# Bind to storyboard defined inside a UserControl from the parent window

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, resources

I just got my storyboard working, now I'm trying to encapsulate all of the functionality into a UserControl.

The goal is to take a button on my window, and have it start a storyboard (that slides the user control into view) that is defined within my UserControl, then when a button within the UserControl is clicked trigger yet another storyboard in the user control (to slide the the UserControl out.)

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438795/controlling-a-usercontrols-storyboard-from-the-parent-window-in-wpf-using-only-x), which seems quite similar; however, there's no satisfactory answer there and additionally, I'm open to other solutions to achieve my goal.

My assumption is that my UserControl should know how to "slide" itself into view and out of view, this control is basically a glorified input dialog so it will be told to "show" it self externally, but only it will know when it hide itself.

I would be OK with the animation/storyboarding being defined outside the control, but if that is best (which seems to be the consensus from the question above) -- how would I "slide-out" when the OK or Cancel button is pushed from within the control?

It feels ugly for the Window to perform the "slide-in" and the control to perform "slide-out" -- but that is where the originating control exists.

I'd rather a fully XAML solution; but I'm open to dropping some code in the UserControl. I'm looking for a robust and easy solution, because once I get this working, I have several additional UserControls to fit into this mold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should try [Visual States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?

Comment: That looks exactly like what I'm looking for, but I can't find any good examples of usage in my scenario.

Comment: @Nate: Create visual states in the layout root of your user control. Then add dependency property which defines your state, for instance `IsInInputMode`. When the property changes to `true` - go to input state, another case - to normal state.

Comment: Do you have an example of such? I've been hunting down but I'm not finding anything simple enough to really get me going.

Comment: How do I bind the DP in my View to the ViewModel?

Comment: @Nate: I prepared a simple sample for you with visual states and binding to ViewModel. You can download it here: [VisualStateSample](http://cid-09f9aac932650216.office.live.com/self.aspx/Common/VisualStateSample.7z).

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do the binding inside the control, doing it outside seems to make it work. I can't set DataContext then, but I can work around that.